# Unable to remove a class from an element once it has been added

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Problem is recreatable at the following url :

http://streeten-new.streeten.co.uk/

- click the hamburger to open the navigation
- click "services"
- click "< services" inside the submenu to *try* and go back

For some reason, removeClass is not removing the 'submenuActive" class. I know for sure I am targeting the right element, because adding a test class to it works without issue.

I have tried using pure javascript instead of jQuery to do this, I have tried changing the css directly with jQuery, rather than adding/removing a class - in all cases I'm unable to undo any changes I make to this element when the submenu first opens.

It's frustrating because opening dev tools and highlighting

```
<ul class="submenuActive">
```

then unticking the

```
.submenuActive {
    left: 0!important;
}
```

rule hides the submenu exactly as I want this to work, for some reason I just cannot get this working on click.

HTML Code added:

```
<nav>
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul >
                <li><a href="#">Studio</a></li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#">Projects</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#">Services</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="menuTitle"><span class="backArrow">&#10094</span> Services</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Online Marketing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <a id="tel" href="tel:02076313720"><button>Call us now</button></a>
    <!--        <p>for your free design consultation</p>-->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Javascript Code added:

```
$(".parent").click(function(){
        $(this).find("ul").first().addClass("submenuActive");
    });

    $(".menuTitle").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("ul").removeClass("submenuActive");
        $(this).closest("ul").addClass("test");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the submenu item, the click event bubbles up the DOM and re-triggers the click on the parent. Try to suppress that with:

```
$(".menuTitle").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest("ul").removeClass("submenuActive");
    $(this).closest("ul").addClass("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the class by doing this :

In html :

> `<ul class="submenuActive" onclick="RemoveClass()">`

In Jquery

```
<script>
function RemoveClass()
{
$(this).removeClass("submenuActive");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made i work using `.parent("ul").removeClass("submenuActive");` instead of `.closest()`

In the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) ,

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Since the `$(this)` represents one dom element in this case, you will never be able to get a set of elements. So the `.closest()` doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking on **.menuTitle** it is firing event of **.parent** as well .For a solution you need to stopprogating the event from child to parent

Use `event.stopPropagation(); to do this thing`

```
  $(".parent").click(function(){
        $(this).find("ul").first().addClass("submenuActive");
    });

    $(".menuTitle").click(function(event){
        $(this).closest("ul").removeClass("submenuActive");
        $(this).closest("ul").addClass("test");
         event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: How's this different from the solution I proposed? Oh and BTW, your function won't work unless you pass in the event parameter.